# I paid for a .APK to be developed. What additional files should they send me?

Tags: android

They have sent me a finished .APK . What other files do I need to request so that somebody else can develop it further in future?

Comment: Depends on your contract with the developer. They might have to send you the source code.

Comment: Is source code the only way someone else can easily develop it ?

Comment: The source code is the only way someone else can develop it at all.

Comment: Thank you buddy. I believe it's possible to reverse engineer but it would take longer than building from scratch hah. Anyways many thanks

Comment: And most important the signing key used. Without it you can't publish updates on Google Play Store (assuming the first version was published this way).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your contract with the developer, you could also need the source code of the application.

If you ever want to switch to another company or developer, in order for them to continue where the others left, they will need the source code of your app. Without the source code, you cannot make any changes to app and publish new versions of it to the Play Store.

For completeness, mentioning what people said in the comments:

- the build files of your project (e.g. Gradle configs)
- the signing key used to publish the app on the Play Store

HTH

Comment: I would also include the used build files (for a regular Java/Kotlin Android app the gradle build scripts) into what should be delivered.

Comment: They are part of the source repository aren’t they?

Comment: Build files are usually included in a repository, but you never know if the original app developer agrees to hand over the complete repository. If not you have to make sure to exactly specify what you expect to retrieve.